# Failed to save settings. Please restart Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

The errors say

> Unable to save settings
>   Failed to save settings. Please restart Android Studio

[image: Here]

The popups are constant and so annoying. How do I solve that?

Comment: What settings you are trying to sve?

Comment: You have done some settings which is incomplete. Better to give correct path to your sdk and restart it again using invalidate cache and restart from file in toolbar.

Comment: @GrIsHu Im doing nothing! Literally not even touching the keyboard and messages appear. Azhar osws already tried invalidating.

Comment: Have you tried to restart and invalidate cache your android studio?

Comment: Yes both. It's still doing the errors, even if it lets me work without issues

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, turns out the I ran out of free space on the partition I had Studio installed, causing it to NOT save the IDE settings anymore.

In my case I run Arch Linux, so to easily gain some free space I simply cleared Pacman's cache like this: #pacman -Sc

Comment: Quite and old question, I want to give some closure saying that it fixed itself with an update.

Comment: @Ddddddd Nope. It's not. I've faced the same today with Android Studio 2.3.1